# How can I reproduce the text strip that's moving in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have attached the video to explain what I'm asking about, is there a library or a code snippet that I can use to make this animated text box?
[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/deanhet/react-native-text-ticker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use react-native-ticker-text package it will do what you wants.

link is attached.